# Erro em função de UPDATE no PHP com PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Esse código não consegue encontrar os registros, e traz que a variável `$lista` é indefinida.

Meu HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        include_once '../classes/Sistema2/Administrador.class.php';

    ?>
    <form action="Crud.php" method="post" id="none">
        <input type="hidden" name="acao" id="acao" value="<?php echo isset($_GET["id"])?'atualizar':'';?>">
        Nome:<input type="text" id="none" name="nome" value="<?php echo $lista['nome']?>">
        email:<input type="text" id="none" name="email" value="<?php echo $lista['email']?>">
        cpf:<input type="text" id="none" name="cpf" value="<?php echo $lista['cpf']?>">
        salario:<input type="text" id="none" name="salario" value="<?php echo $lista['salario']?>">
        <input type="submit" value="atualizar" name="atualizar">

    </form>    
</body>
```

Esse código fica no meu `Crud.php` e um arquivo que recebe do `post` e faz a chamada com a `class` `Administrador`

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
                if($_POST["acao"] == "atualizar"):
                    $administrador = new Administrador();
                    $administrador->atualizar((strip_tags(trim($_POST['nome']))),(trim($_POST['email'])),(trim($_POST['cpf'])),(trim($_POST['salario'])));
                endif;    
            }
```

Esse código fica na `class`:

```
public function atualizar($nome,$email,$cpf,$salario){
        $sql_atualizar = "UPDATE administrador SET nome=:nome, email=:email, cpf=:cpf salario=:salario WHERE id = :id";
        print_r($sql_atualizar);
        try{
            $query_atualizar = $this->conn()->prepare($sql_atualizar);
            $query_atualizar->bindValue(':nome',$nome,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_atualizar->bindValue(':email',$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_atualizar->bindValue(':cpf',$cpf,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_atualizar->bindValue(':salario',$salario,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            //echo "<script>alert('Administrador alterado com sucesso! ')</script>";
            header('location: Index.php');

        }catch(PDOException $err){
            echo " Erro: ".$err->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Huuum, code review :D. Já comenta aquele `header()` p começar.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro defina um campo hidden com id do registro em seu form.

```
<form action="Crud.php" method="post" id="none">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $lista['id'; ?> " />
```

Em `Crud.php` verifique se o id existe, caso sim é um update do contrario é um insert.

```
if(isset($_GET["id"] && ctype_digit($_GET["id"])){
   $administrador = new Administrador();
   $administrador->atualizar('valores ...');
```

Agora crie o bind respectivo para o id em `atualizar()` e não esqueça de chamar `execute()` do contrario sua consulta não chegará no banco de dados quanto e nem será executada.

```
$query_atualizar->bindValue(':salario',$salario,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_atualizar->bindValue(':id', $_GET["id"]);
if(!$query_atualizar->execute()){
   print_r($$query_atualizar->errorInfo()):
}else{
   echo 'sucesso';
}
```

**Sugestões**

Essa linha está bem longa, é uma boa oportunidade para criar uma função ou método que faça um sanitização nas entradas do usuário.

```
 $administrador->atualizar((strip_tags(trim($_POST['nome']))),(trim($_POST['email'])),(trim($_POST['cpf'])),(trim($_POST['salario'])))
```

Nova função

```
function sanitizar($input){
     return trim(strip_tags($input));
}

$administrador->atualizar(sanitizar($_POST['nome']),sanitizar($_POST['email']),sanitizar($_POST['cpf']),sanitizar($_POST['salario']));
```